# What are the conditions for inserting modules into other modules in angular for DI purposes?

Tags: angularjs

I have a an angular app and in it I can see this coffee in the app.coffee file....

```
app = angular.module 'app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource',
  'ui.router',
  'app.filters',
  'app.services',
  'app.directives',
  'app.controllers',
  'app.templates',
]

angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
angular.module('app.controllers',[])
angular.module('app.directives', [])
angular.module('app.filters', [])
angular.module('app.templates', [])
angular.module('app.models', [])
```

I don't really understand why I have to inject **ngResource** into the **app.services** module direct AND into the **app** module. Surely I can just wire up All dependencies into the app module and then it will allow global access to the rest of the modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

`app = angular.module 'app', [
      'ngRoute',
      'ngResource',
      'ui.router',
      'app.filters',
      'app.services',
      'app.directives',
      'app.controllers',
      'app.templates',
    ]`

this means these are the dependencies of your `app`.

When you write

`angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])`

this means `app.services` has a dependency `ngResource`. About your question as to why you need to write it again. It is fairly simple, `app.services`  uses `ngResource`. If you don't want the whole app to have `ngResouce` dependency, you can ignore it in the first line, but it has to be there for `app.services`

You can read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Comment: so can I leave it out of the 

angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])

line and still have access to it in my app.services module?

Comment: ONLY if another module doesn't have this dependency.

Comment: Sorry to confirm : if I want the application to have access to the entire app then it goes into 'app' and so I never need to put it in app.services, but if I want it in app.services only then I put it in there. If that is the case then it is useless having it in both places. I may as well just have it in 'app' because my whole app needs it. Is that right?

Comment: Correction : From your 1st comment :
Yes, if you have already injected dependency in `app` then no need to include it again while declaring `app.services` module.

Your 2nd comment: Yes.